# SQL Select query to get data from the parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have two tables. Table 1,a parent table and Table 2, a child table

**Table 1**:

```
T1_id  T1_Name
-------------
1    Sunday
2    Monday
3.   Tuesday
4.   Thursday
5.   Friday
6.   Saturday
7.   Rain
8.   Wind
9.   Snow
```

**Table 2**:

```
 T2_id  Day  Climate
 -------------------
  1      2   9
  2      3   8
  3      5   7
```

In the table 2 corresponding Id from the table 2 is stored, My expected result is

```
 T2_id   Day         Climate
 -----------------------------
  1      Monday      Snow
  2      Tuesday3    Wind
  3      Friday      Rain
```

I have tried something with inner joins, But it returns only the matched records. I need all the rows irrespective of NULL Values in the columns. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT T2.T2_id,y.T1_Name,x.T1_Name FROM T2 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 y ON T2.Day = y.T1_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 x ON T1.Climate = x.T1_id
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN will display the NULL values if no match is Found.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks for your help guys, Cheers!